# Importing Eclipse project on IntelliJ results in a package error

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I use to work on Eclipse and now I want to migrate to IntelliJ.
On Eclipse I had a set of projects on the same workspace.
I am trying to map that in modules on the same project, according to instructions from other questions.

Nevertheless, after importing them IntelliJ states the following error:

> Package name 'a.b.c.d' does not correspond to the file path 'source.src.a.b.c.d'

This error just happens in a specific module.

After some reading about the error, I tried to create a new project for test purpose and import just the broken module and it worked as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably try using File -> New -> "Create new project from Existing source" and Intellij would properly format the folder structure

Comment: This issue could be caused by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899453/intellij-source-root-is-not-handled-correctly. Please check this link too.

Answer (score 0):

The source directories for the project were apparently not imported correctly. Since for Java, directory structure = package path, if IntelliJ thinks that your sources reside in `/` (instead of `/source/src`), it will think that the package name should be `source.src.a.b.c.d`.

Basically, go to **File** -> **Project Structure**, find the proper Module, then on the right hand side remove the root directory as a source folder and add all the relevant subdirectories as source folders (i.e. remove "`.`" and add "`src/source`").

Comment: I tried this before, for some reason it messes up all the package. I am almost giving up and downloading Eclipse.

If I open the module again it will still states that the "." is there and the "src/source"

Comment: You seem to have overlapping source roots. If you have both "." and "src/source", you should remove "." and just leave the "src/source". Otherwise, it will include the same packages twice, but with different relative paths, which is asking for trouble.

Comment: Also, since I am a migrant from Eclipse myself, I can tell you how I did it: you should follow stillLearning's advice from the comment above and import each project as an IntelliJ project (instead of as a module), then create a new meta-project and add all the already-imported IntelliJ projects as modules (via "Module from existing sources...").

Comment: I had to download eclipse again due to work urgencies. I will test again this new approach that you said. Thanks in advice!