# IntelliJ: Source root is not handled correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following project structure:

```
ModuleName (=Content Root)
  |---src
  |    |---com
  |         |---company
  |             |---file1.java
  |             |---file2.java
  |---test-src
  |    |---com
  |         |---company
  |             |---test.java
  |--- .classpath
  |--- .project
```

This was an Eclipse project initially, and I need to import it in IntelliJ.

However, everytime I try to import it, IntelliJ is completely confused with the source root folder.

Looking at the java source files, I get the following error in the package declaration:

```
package com.company;
```

> Error: Package name 'com.company' does not correspond to the file path 'src/com.company'

and

> Error: Package name 'com.company' does not correspond to the file path 'test-src/com.company'

I correctly marked the 'src' and 'test-src' folders as source-roots in IntelliJ. However, it always thinks that these folders are part of the package hierarchy.

I have this problem in 3 of about 30 different modules. All modules are structured the same, and I don't really see any reason why IntelliJ works for most of them, but fails for those three.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Double check no other folder above or below is marked as sources root, only `src`. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

Comment: There are no source folders above. Also, creating a verifible example is not possible: When creating a new IntelliJ project and importing the modules from scratch, it often works correctly. But after some time (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours or days), it suddenly breaks and the problem appears again. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in IntelliJ, but I have no idea how it is triggered and therefore I have no idea how I can work around it.

Comment: Note: I already spent several days trying to resolve this issue. Clearing IntelliJ-caches, re-installing IntelliJ, re-creating the whole module from scratch, using another PC always lead to the same problem. Many times it works in the beginning, but after some time it breaks again. But again -
 only for some specific modules - the vast majority of them is ok.

Comment: This issue is tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244279.
Anyone who experiences this bug could try the "The possible workaround" section in this link to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For completeness' sake - if anyone runs into the same problem with a similar setup, here is the solution:

Another module (let's call it module B) had a dependency on the .jar file generated by module A. This normally works perfectly fine, and the required .jar can be found in module B's lib folder. The issue was that module B's .classpath file (which was used to import the modules into IntelliJ) included the following entry (I assume it was generated by eclipse at some earlier point):

`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ModuleA.jar" sourcepath="/ModuleA/" />`

Now it seems like IntelliJ became extremely confused by this sourcepath entry (as it doesn't point to a valid location) and this somehow affected module A's packaging structure.
What's interesting about this (and made it a huge pain to debug and find the actual issue) is that the error didn't manifest itself in module B where the problematic .classpath file was located (because IntelliJ doesn't show a warning that the sources imported from the .classpath file were invalid), but rather in the parent module A.

Removing the sourcepath entry (or pointing it to a valid location, i.e.: lib/ModuleA.jar) fixed the problem.

Comment: Where can i find this .classpath file where the change has to be made?

Comment: The .classpath file was used by the original eclipse project that we imported the sources from. Normally it resides in the root folder of each project/module.

Comment: In IntelliJ idea, when i import a project created in eclipse, i have the same problem as you mention above. But i don't see any .classpath file in the root . All i see is an .iml file in the root folder.

Comment: TBH I can't remember all the details since this issue is 2 years old.
But I would suggest to look into your .iml file. I suppose one of the entries there is not like the others and looks weird (with an incorrect path).

Alternatively take a look at the original .classpath file (before you imported into IntelliJ, and fix the problem there (remove the invalid classpathentry)

Comment: Oh yeah and look at ALL the projects - IIRC the error actually manifested not in the project with the broken .iml file, but rather in a dependent project.